# Lambda to Expression tree conversion

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I will keep it really simple,

How do I get expression tree out of lambda??

or from query expression ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You must assign the lambda to a different type:

```
// Gives you a delegate:
Func<int, int> f = x => x * 2;
// Gives you an expression tree:
Expression<Func<int, int>> g = x => x * 2;
```

The same goes for method arguments. However, once you've assigned such a lambda expression to a `Func<>` type, you can't get the expression tree back.

Comment: Delegate is a better term than lambda, in the first case. Both are lambda expressions, one implicitly converted to an anonymous delegate, other an expression tree.

Comment: @nawfal *`f`* is a delegate. But `x => x * 2` is a lambda expression (as you yourself noted). Your comment implies that I said something different but I really didn’t.

Comment: You said the second expression gives you an expression tree. Analogous to that, the first lambda expression should *give you a delegate*, not a *lambda* - which is what your first comment is. Not nitpicking, just mentioning so that it helps someone in future.

Comment: @nawfal Ah, I see it now – I didn’t look at the comments before. You’re right, I’ll change it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks for the tip. I want to understand why `x => x * 2` is assignable to both `Func<int,int>` and `Expression<Func<int,int>>`? What's the CLR type of `x => x * 2`? And does that mean `Func<int,int>` and `Expression<Func<int,int>>` derive from the same base type?

Comment: @KFL, the lambda expression itself is an expression you typed as program code, not necessarily corresponding to a specific type. ``Func<a, b>`` and ``Expression<Func<a, b>>`` don't have to derive from the same base type, just ``int`` and ``float`` don't derive from the same base type when you say ``int x = 42`` and ``float y = 42``

Comment: @ohw are you sure about that? I've been told that "every expression always has an unambiguous type." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311450/c-sharp-class-as-one-value-in-class-mimic-int-behaviour/47311759#comment81586832_47311759

Answer (score 11):

Konrad's reply is exact. You need to assign the lambda expression to `Expression<Func<...>>` in order for the compiler to generate the expression tree. If you get a lambda as a `Func<...>`, `Action<...>` or other delegate type, all you have is a bunch of IL instructions.

If you really need to be able to convert an IL-compiled lambda back into an expression tree, you'd have to decompile it (e.g. do what Lutz Roeder's Reflector tool does). I'd suggest having a look at the [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library, which provides advanced IL manipulation support and could save you quite some time.

Answer (score 8):

Just to expand on Konrad's answer, and to correct Pierre, you can still generate an Expression from an IL-compiled lambda, though it's not terribly elegant. Augmenting Konrad's example:

```
// Gives you a lambda:
Func<int, int> f = x => x * 2;

// Gives you an expression tree:
Expression<Func<int, int>> g = x => f(x);
```

Comment: This **does not** give you the expression tree of the original lamda, it gives you a **new** expression tree that calls the delegate. Nothing more.

Comment: The question is not specific on getting an *equivalent* expression. For in-memory LINQ this provides identical functionality. Of course it could not be parsed properly by any LINQ provider.

Answer (score 0):

A runtime alternative is to use this project - https://github.com/kostat/XLinq :

```cs
// Gives you a lambda:
Func<int, int> f = x => x * 2;

// Gives you an expression tree:
Expression<Func<int, int>> g = ExpressionTree.Parse(f);
```