# Get a parameter's old name

Tags: c#, .net, logging, naming-conventions

When I am tracing, I think it would be useful to do something like

```
//In the main function
{
  Log(myVariable);
}
```

Which sends the variable to a generic function like this

```
//In the Logger file
public static void TraceMessage<T>(T aVariable)
{
   string oldName=GetOldName(aVariable);
}
```

I want "myVariable" to be assigned to `oldName`. What should `GetOldName` do?

Something similar was asked here:

[get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

But in all of those cases, "aVariable" is assigned to `oldName`.

Update: Old name is what the parameter/variable was called before it was sent to the function. I use it as a variable here just for ease of explaining.
The reason for this is debugging. When my program receives an error I would like to know what the value of my variables are. I currently have to send Log(*the error*, *the variable name*, *the variable value*). When you write 1000 of the these Debug statements you think of ways this could be simplified. What I am asking would simplify the problem.

Why did my question get downvoted and how can I improve the question?

Comment: What do you mean by `oldName` ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  I also don't think it's necessary.  Why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: Don't let the downvotes get to you. I've upvoted you since I feel it's a valid question, even if it there doesn't exist a way of achieving what you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

This information needs to be captured and provided by the caller. In C# 6, it can be easily achieved using the `nameof` operator, although you'll need to apply this in your caller code:

```
Log(myVariable, nameof(myVariable));
```

**Edit**: If you only want to specify your variable once, you can use:

```
Log(() => myVariable);
```

And define your `Log` method as:

```
public static void Log<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    string oldName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    object value = expression.Compile().Invoke();
}
```

However, this will be much slower than the alternative, and [is not guaranteed behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071271/1149773).

Comment: The edit is a very good solution, but if there is one without the () =>, it would be better.

Comment: In that case, leave the question open. I'd be curious to see whether one exists. For the record, I personally wouldn't use the lambdas in my code due to the issues I mentioned (speed and lack of spec); I'd prefer to go with `Log(myVariable, nameof(myVariable))`.